# I'm having an error in copy data activity in ADF, the PL fails instantly

Tags: azure-data-factory

My PL is instantly failing and I'm receiving this error message: [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyjoC.png), which is weird because it was working yesterday and no adjustments were made. Upon checking in Debug the error detail is this [error detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjEty.png).

I tried rerunning the PL multiple times but I'm getting the same error. I also tried to limit the run on certain activity and the run succeeds, but if copy data is added it instantly fails. I've also make sure that no changes were made I compared my copy data activity to similar PL.

Comment: Please attach a screenshot or json of your pipeline, so we can see to what object this error references.

Answer (score 0):

- The issue looks related to the wrong activity referencing. Either you are trying to reference to activity B from activity A which comes later in the pipeline
- If A is connected to B like this in series:

  A--> B

  Then B can reference A's output but A can't reference B's output
- Make sure the all activities which are getting referenced by another activity comes before that.
- Additionally, make sure the acitivity name and the reference expression are matching .
- Also, you can try avoiding special characters like '-' in the activity names.